# Choose column based on preferences (Pandas DF)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe to get the best contract for each Code based on a list of preferences, which is:

```
F, N, J, V, Z, U, M, H, X, Q, K, G
```

`Code  C1  C2  C3
 R1    N   Q   0 
 R2    F   0   0 
 R3    V   Z   U`

Required output:

`Code  C1  C2  C3  Contract
 R1    N   Q   0     N
 R2    F   0   0     F
 R3    V   Z   U     V`

I have managed to do this in Excel by ranking the preferences from 12 to 1, so that I used VLOOKUP to get the rank for each contract and then got the best one.

I thought about using MERGE but can´t seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your string to numerical values and then use `Dataframe.max()`. I assume you "hardly" coded your list, but it may be done with iterative method instead:

```py
cleanup_cat = {"C1":     {"F": 15, "N": 14 ...},
               "C2": {"F": 15, "N": 14 ...},
               "C3": {"F": 15, "N": 14 ...}}

df.replace(cleanup_cat , inplace=True)

# Now values are coded into numbers. You can just use max operation

df['Contract'] = df.loc[:, ['C1','C2','C3']].max(axis=1)
```

(replace `...` in the rest of the list. number 15 was arbitrary)

Comment: Thanks Roim, that did the trick. The only change I made was to put max(axis=1) to make it work.

Comment: yeah you are right. I'll edit my post for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column that constructed from each row. You should put the contracts into a format that will speed that up which I have done from a dictionary.

```
priorities = ['F', 'N', 'J', 'V', 'Z', 'U', 'M', 'H', 'X', 'Q', 'K', 'G' ]
priorities_dict = {
    letter: index 
    for letter, index in enumerate(priorities)
}
df['Contract'] = [
    priorities[
        min(
            priorities_dict[row['C1']], 
            priorities_dict[row['C2']], 
            priorities_dict[row['C3']]
       )
    ]
    for row in df
] 

# Print the DataFrame 
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, but that did not work for me. It was probably because if the type of the data, I don´t know that much to tell you why it didn't work.